# Compare two dictionaries returned from REST framework using pytest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to test my django application with pytest. I am trying to send an object like so:

{
"x" :1
"y" :2 
....
}

What my view does, is returning a list of dictionaries, so in my scenario a list with this one sent dictionary.

I want to check if my sent data equals my data when I do a get call. My problem is that the two dictionaries are always evaluated to false.

This is what I am doing:

```
 def test_post_data_is_get_data(self):
        url = api_reverse('urlname') #I get the url
        data = sent_data #this is my dict I am sending defined as a big dict in my code
        response_create = client.post(url, data, format='json') # I save the response
        response_get = client.get(url) # I get the created data back
        print(type(response_create.data)) #debugging
        print(type(data))
        print(type(response_create.content))
        print(type(response_get))


        assert response_create == response_get
```

The types I am printing out is:

```
<class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

Doesn't matter how I compare it is never the same. I tried comparing sent data with:

```
1) response_create.content == response_get.content
2) response_create.data == response_get.data
3) response_create.data == response_get[0]
4) response_create.data == response_get.first() ## error that byte like object has not attribute first
```

Since I am calling a list view I should be getting a list with one dict back. The first element should be the same data as the sent one.... But it is never the same.

I think what's going wrong is: I am comparing a dict with a list with one dict inside. Both are given back as bytes. So I think I need to compare the dict which is given back as bytes with the first element of the list that is also in bytes. Do I make sense?

Anyone has an idea what I could do? Or maybe a better idea how to structure the test? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using debugger to inspect the objects? `print` is not your friend.

Comment: print helped me so often I'd call him almost my best friend ;). But you're right of course, I should use the debugger more. Will do, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the print statements show the `response_create.data` is a `rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict` which is a subclass of [`OrderedDict`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py#L9).

The return of the `client.get` is a Django [`Response` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response) which means that you'll need to use the `json` method to get the content.

So something like:

```
response_create = client.post(url, data, format='json')
response_get = client.get(url)
assert dict(response_create.data) == response_get.json()[0]
```

Comment: thanks so much lee-pai-long. It still throws me a ```AssertionError: assert {'accepted_st...sa12345', ...} == [{'accepted_st...a12345', ...}]```

Comment: so I guess I need to pick somehow the first element of the ```response_get.json()```

Comment: thanks again lee-pai-long, for pointing me there. If you want add this to your answer for future people.